# Casting a list of objects to their interface type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I know I can cast an object from its own type to its interface type like so:

```
IMyInterface myValue = (IMyInterface)MyObjectThatImplementsMyInterface;
```

How can I cast `IList<MyClassThatImplementMyInterface>` to `IList<IMyInterface>`?

Comment: IList to IList? They look the same type to me!

Comment: The angle brackets weren't escaped so they looked like bogus tags and Markdown ate them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I answered the same question [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/how-to-convert-list-of-derived-class-objects-to-list-of-base-class-objects/1817332#1817332), although for base classes rather than interfaces.

The way to make this work is to iterate over the list and cast the elements. This can be done using ConvertAll:

```
IList<A> listOfA = new List<C>().ConvertAll(x => (A)x);
```

You could also use Linq:

```
IList<A> listOfA = new List<C>().Cast<A>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't help you now, but note that C# 4.0 will introduce co/contravariance for interfaces so you'll be able to directly cast certain collection interfaces.  Though I'm not sure if `IList<>` will be one of them (the interface has to be 'safely' covariant/contravariant)

Some links:

[Use Covariance and Contravariance in VS 2010 Part I?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee672314.aspx)

[Use Covariance and Contravariance in VS 2010 Part II?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee672319.aspx)