# Casting typed binding list

Tags: c#, oop

I have `BindingList<BaseClass>` variable. Then I want to assign it to BindingList but getting error that cannot convert... is it possible?

```
BindingList<BaseClass> base;
...
BindingList<ChildClass> child = new BindingList<ChildClass>();
...
base = child;
```

This last line is giving error that cannot convert one type to another. I understand the lists are eventually different types, however, from my perspective the list types can be casted because of inheritance.

Comment: what if you have a `anotherchild` class - you could mix those up with your `base` (see *co/contravariance*)

Comment: I think there is an answer for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass

Comment: By that reasoning, `List<object> o = new List<string>();` should be valid, but it's not (nor should it be - think about why).

Comment: Question is how to have a base pointer and then bunch of children, then be able to store children in the base variable.

Answer (score 3):

> from my perspective the list types can be casted because of inheritance

No they can't - take this example:

```
List<Fruit> base;

List<Apple> apples = new List<Apple>();

base = apples;   

// if that were legal, then this could happen:

base.Add(new Orange());  // fail because a list of apples can't store an orange.
```

You can cast the *items* to a new list:

```
base = child.Cast<BaseClass>().ToList();
```

now `base` is a *separate* list that can contain any instance of `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 0):

What you see here is the lack of variance in generics in .Net. It is there by design.

Basically this is there to keep you from doing the following:

```
List<Giraff> giraffs = new List<Giraff>();
List<Animal> animals = giraffs;
```

...then somewhere in you code

```
animals.Add(new Horse()); //run-time error
```

Basically the check keeps you from doing this in run-time and prevents this in compile time. Funny enough, this is not true for arrays. But that's another story...

Here is a MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) about it.

Comment: I think we can blame Java for the array inconsistency!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `BindingList<BaseClass>`, you will be able to add items of type `ChildClass` and `AnotherChildClass` to the list.  This is not valid for `BindingList<ChildClass>`, so you cannot assign the later to the former.