# Generic c# property type

Tags: c#, abstraction

I have three classes, two of which inherit from a base class, and the third which I would like to reference one of the other two depending on the state of the application.

```
public class Batch
{        
    public Batch() { }
}

public class RequestBatch : Batch
{
    public RequestBatch(string batchJobType) : base(batchJobType) { }

    public override int RecordCount
    {
        get { return Lines.Count; }
    }
}

public class ResponseBatch : Batch
{       
    public ResponseBatch(string batchJobType) : base(batchJobType) { }

    public ResponseBatch(int BatchJobRunID)
    { }
}
```

Sometimes I have an instance of Child1 instantiated, and sometimes I need Child2.  However, I have model that I want to pass around my application to keep everything in one place, but I want a way to make the property that holds Child1 and Child2 generic,  for example:

```
public class BatchJob {
   public List<Batch> Batches { get; set; }
}
```

And then later do this

```
public List<RequestBatch> GetBatches(...) {}

var BatchJob = new BatchJob();
BatchJob.Batches = GetBatches(...);
```

However, the compiler yells at me saying it can't implicitly convert Child1 to (its base type) Parent.

I get red squiggles under "= GetBatches(...." saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Is there a way to generify the Property so it can take any abstract of type Parent?

Thanks!

Comment: This should work. Can you show the real code?

Comment: That should not happen; classes are implicitly convertible to their base types.  Please show a complete example.

Comment: Give a *complete* and *minimal* example, and *state the error message*. A question like this is basically "something is broken" -- we don't know what.

Comment: Why do people keep upvoting this question?

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev Because it was his first question and he described it fairly well, even if the code is incomplete. I upvoted because I'm tired of seeing really bad quality questions being posted all day.

Comment: Do you have the right assemblies and references in place?

Comment: I bet its because you are creating you properties in a class where you did not include your reference to parent. Namespace or using error

Comment: I up voted because someone was complaining :-D

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/category/covariance-and-contravariance/

Comment: @MatthewWhited  That fixed it!  The compiler error was distracting me.  I thought it couldn't convert RequestBatch to Batch, but it couldn't convert a List<RequestBatch> to List<Batch>  I changed the Batches property to type IEnumerable<Batch> and it worked.  I even tried that once, not sure what I had done differently the first time. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah... I thought about writing it up as an answer but it has been don't tons of times here on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass)

Comment: You could use an interface for the common properties of your model classes and make the use the interface as the type of your RunningJob property.

Comment: @JeffreyHaines Ok, that makes sense.

Comment: Now that you've clarified the question: this question is asked a lot here. A list of turtles cannot be used as a list of animals because you can put a tiger into a list of animals. A list of animals cannot be used as a list of turtles because it might contain a tiger. Therefore a list of animals and a list of turtles are totally incompatible.  But a list of turtles *can* be used as a **sequence** of animals, because there's no way to put a tiger into a sequence. IEnumerable has no "add" method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One option...**

```
public new IEnumerable<RequestBatch> GetBatches(...) {
    get 
    {
        return base.GetBatches(...).OfType<RequestBatch>();
    }
}
```

**Another...**

If you don't need to modify the collection then just change from `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`

**More Info...**

- [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [A contravariance conundrum](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/29/a-contravariance-conundrum/)

Comment: @OP: If it is considered an error for `base.GetBatches` contain anything other than instances of `RequestBatch`, you may wish to replace `OfType` with `Cast` so that such an error is detectable.

Answer (score 1):

The code snipped you show does work. There is no compiler error:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var rj = new RunningJob();
        rj.Property = new Child1();
        rj.Property = new Child2();
    }
}
public class RunningJob { 
    public Parent Property { get; set; }
}
public class Parent {    }
public class Child1 : Parent {    }
public class Child2 : Parent {    }
```

The only issue that comes with this code is that `Property` is of type `Parent`. So you cannot call methods that are specific for `Child1/Child2`. This can be done using constraints on generic type parameters on class `RunningJob` :

```
public class RunningJob<TParent> where TParent : Parent
{
    public TParent Property { get; set; }
}
```

Hence, now it is ensured that `Property` is of type `Parent` or any derived types.