# Set generic type property in derived classes

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic type `G<T> where T : A`, where `A` is an abstract class. In each class `B` derived from `A` I want to have a field of type `G<B>`, without writing repetetive code, however I'm not sure if it's even possible. One way to do this would be

```
abstract class A
{
    protected object g;

    protected abstract void SetG();

    public A()
    {
        SetG();
    }
}

class B : A
{
    protected override void SetG()
    {
        this.g = new G<B>();
    }

    public B() : base() {}
}
```

But this would mean a lot of repetetive code in every derived class. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add an extra abstract class in between:

```
public abstract class A<T> : A where T : A
{
    protected override void SetG()
    {
        this.g = new G<T>();
    }
}
```

...then, update your B declaration to:

```
public class B : A<B>
{
    public B() : base() { }
}
```

Comment: Hm yes that's certainly a better solution than mine. Thanks! I'll wait some time in case someone else thinks of something

Comment: This is the solution you are looking for. You might want to think about just naming the between class something like `A<T>` though. If you want to see this pattern somewhere else you can look at the Collections and their Generic implementations also.

Comment: Ha!  Good point, @MattRowland!  Not sure how that escaped me. :)  Updating the answer to use that name instead.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I think I'll just change `A` to `A<T>`. Thanks guys, this is a really clever way to "tell" the base class what's deriving from it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are trying to do is a [Covariant Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass). See this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654054.aspx) on using delegates and see if that works for you. Look in the section "Using Delegates with Covariant Type Parameters".

In your A:, create a delegate:

```
Func<G<A>> GetG;
```

Then, in your derived classes, set this func pointer to a function of type

```
Func<G<B>>
```

Bingo!