# Return a List<type> with a dynamically selected type while also casting to that type (C#)

Tags: c#, casting, system.reflection

Resolved, see solution at the end of the post.

---

I have a method that returns a List of attachments. I have three types of attachments, which all extend a class called `GenericAttachment`:

```
GenericAttachment
||
==> FormA_Attachment
==> FormB_Attachment
==> FormC_Attachment
```

I also have different form types, which all extend a class called `GenericForm`:

```
GenericForm
||
==> FormA
==> FormB
==> FormC
```

The method must take a `Type` argument which is either FormA, FormB or FormC, and return the attachments of the appropriate type.

I've tried this first:

```
public static List<GenericAttachment> GetAllAttachmentsByFormID<T>(int sqlFormId, Type type) where T : GenericForm
{
        //this returns e.g. FormA_Attachment based on FormA as the input
        Type attachmentType = GetAttachmentTypeByFormType(type);

        //Call a generic function (overload of this one) 
        //that returns all attachments and requires a specific type argument.
        //Meanwhile, .Invoke()'s return type is just an `object`
        var attachments = typeof(AttachmentManager)
                              .GetMethod("GetAllAttachmentsByFormID", new[] { typeof(int) }) // select the correct overload for the method
                              .MakeGenericMethod(attachmentType)
                              .Invoke(new AttachmentManager(), new object[] { sqlFormId });

        return (List<GenericAttachment>)attachments;
}
```

However, the cast fails at runtime ("failed to cast").

Then I tried a dumber way with if/else statements, but it doesn't compile because "Cannot convert `List<FormA_Attachment>` to `List<GenericAttachment>`". Tried both using `Convert.ChangeType` and a normal cast, as seen below.

It's weird that it doesn't compile because e.g. `FormA_Attachment` extends `GenericAttachment`.

```
        if (attachmentType == typeof(FormA_Attachment))
        {
            return (List<FormA_Attachment>) Convert.ChangeType(attachments, typeof(List<FormA_Attachment>));
        }
        else if (attachmentType == typeof(FormB_Attachment))
        {
            return (List<FormB_Attachment>)attachments;
        }
        else if (attachmentType == typeof(FormC_Attachment))
        {
            return (List<FormC_Attachment>)attachments;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid attachment class type.");
        }
```

How do I cast the `attachments` into a `List<type>`, where `type` is selected dynamically?

---

**Solution**:

Thanks to @Mikhail Neofitov, the below code worked.

`attachments` has the type `object` because this is what `.Invoke()` returns.

So I cast it to a specific type first, then convert to less specific type using `.OfType<GenericAttachment>().ToList()`.

```
        if (attachmentType == typeof(FormA_Attachment))
        {
            return ((List<FormA_Attachment>) Convert.ChangeType(attachments, typeof(List<FormA_Attachment>))).OfType<GenericAttachment>().ToList();
        }
        else if (attachmentType == typeof(FormB_Attachment))
        ... 
        //similar code
```

Comment: need [Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @LeiYang I am trying `return (List<FormA_Attachment>) Convert.ChangeType(attachments, typeof(List<FormA_Attachment>));` but it says "Cannot implicitly convert List<FormA_Attachment> to List<GenericAttachment>.

Comment: how about add another type parameter TResult?

Comment: I cannot pass this parameter to the method, the exact return type must be determined at runtime. I just know that the method will return one of the types that extend `GenericAttachment`.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen because this method must be called with a `<T>` parameter, and that type (FormA_Attachment, FormB_Attachment or FormC_Attachment) is selected at runtime.

Comment: Would help if you could include the code of the AttachmentManager as well, currently we have no idea what it will return. I'm guessing it returns a list of specific types and not the GenericAttachments.

Comment: Just because `FormA_Attachment` inherits from `GenericAttachment` it does not mean that `List<FormA_Attachment>` inherits from `List<GenericAttachment>`.

Comment: Umm, if you know the Invoke() returns an object type but the actual returned type is List<FormA_Attachment>. Why not just cast and enumerate that with yield return? Because you can return FormA_Attachment in the iterator. But you cant return a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# does not allow [types covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/mt654055.aspx), it means that `List<string>` could not simple convert to `List<object>`.

In your case you could use `LINQ` extension method [`OfType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) as following:

```
return attachments.OfType<GenericAttachment>().ToList();
```

Just a note, I guess, you could modify your app architecture to pass resulting type of `GenericArgument` to the generic parameter of `GenericForm` and define an abstract method for returning resulting attachments in the result type. Also, your generic parameter `<T>` is useless, you do not use it in the method body.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize *covariance* here. `List<T>` isn't variant, but it implements `IEnumerable<out T>` which is covariant in T. This means you cannot convert your `object` to the `List<GenericAttachment>`, but you can convert it to an `IEnumerable<GenericAttachment>`. So instead of all those `if`s, you should be able to do the following:

```
return ((IEnumerable<GenericAttachment>)attachments).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass/30662440#30662440). This is an example of memory efficient casting a `List<Derived>` to a `List<Base>`