# cannot convert from Dictionary to IDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to create interface with method

```
void Import(int id, IDictionary<int, IDictionary<int, string>> items);
```

then call this method like

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> items = viewModel.Items
  .GroupBy(t => t.Number)
  .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.ToDictionary(x => x.LanguageId, x => x.Translation));


Import(id, items);
```

I expected that it should works but got an error

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<int, string>>'
```

Why I can't use interface IDictionary here? Should I cast manually?

Comment: The error message you get is to be expected. It's for the same reason that it's a compilation error to assign a `List<Dog>` to a `List<Animal>`, even though you can assign a `Dog` to an `Animal`.

Comment: ToDictionary extension from System.Linq returns a Dictionary not the interface, i suppose the error is when he calls import

Comment: @animalitomaquina - This has to do with covariance. Example: `List<IMonkey>` is not assignable to an instance of type `List<Monkey>` even if `Monkey` implements interface `IMonkey`.

Comment: More explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your assigning type.

```
Dictionary<int, IDictionary<int, string>> items = viewModel.Items
  .GroupBy(t => t.Number)
  .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => (IDictionary<int, string>) t.ToDictionary(x => x.LanguageId, x => x.Translation));
```

Comment: or more formally called "receiver type".

Comment: ToDictionary extension from System.Linq returns a Dictionary not the interface i suppose the error is when he calls import