# c# conversion generic inherited as base returns null

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a class called TabularSectionManager and each Manager linked to TabularBusinessObject.

```
public abstract class TabularSectionManager<T1> : where T1 : TabularBusinessObject
{
    public TabularSectionManager()
    {
    }

    public T1 LinkedTabularBusinessObject { get; set; } 
}

public class PhoneManager : TabularSectionManager<PhoneBo>
{
    public PhoneManager()
    {

    }
}

public class PhoneBo : TabularBusinessObject
{
    public PhoneBo()
    {

    }
}
```

Finally, there is another class stores collection of TabularBusinessObjectManager List.

Compiler is complaining here regarding conversion:

```
List<TabularSectionManager<TabularBusinessObject>> TabularSections { get; set; }

TabularSections.Add(new PhoneManager());
```

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from "PhoneManager" to
>   "TabularSectionManager< TabularBusinessObject >".

Could you pls advice on that?

Thanks.

Comment: _"Compiler is complaining here regarding conversion:"_ - is the compiler message just "there's a problem with this line of code?" Odd. Usually it's more specific than that.

Comment: In other words, what is the complaint made by the compiler?

Comment: `PhoneManager` isn't a derived class of `TabularSectionManager<TabularBusinessObject>`, it's a derived class of `TabularSectionManager<PhoneBo>`. To understand why, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817341/3181933)

Comment: [This is also good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033921/3181933)

Comment: Dear All. I understand the limitation. However, the link you provided are mostly related conversion from List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>. In my case, I am trying adding new instance of DerivedClass to List<BaseClass>. Could you pls help?