# Error in type conversion using reflection method invoke

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a method call as follows:

```
splitByRegex(regexPattern, lines, ref lineIndex, capacity, result =>
{
      List<object> res = result.Select(selector).ToList();
      MessageBox.Show(res[0].GetType().ToString());
      collection.GetType().GetMethod("AddRange").Invoke(collection, new object[] { res });
});
```

`splitByRegex` method will split the data and will give back `result`.

I have to add the obtained `result` to the generic `collection`.

Type of `selector` function: `Func<Tuple<string, string, string>, object>`

Sample selector Function: `x => new Merchant { MerchantName = x.Item1, Count = Convert.ToInt64(x.Item2), Percentage = Convert.ToDecimal(x.Item3) }`

While executing `AddRange` method call using reflection: 
`collection.GetType().GetMethod("AddRange").Invoke(collection, new object[] { res });`

I am getting following error:

**Object of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.Tuple`3[System.String,System.String,System.String],System.Object]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Processing.Merchant]'.**

When I try to print the type of any one object from the `List<object> res` `MessageBox.Show(res[0].GetType().ToString());`, it shows it as `Merchant` type object. So why am I getting this error?

Comment: Because `List<object>` isn't a `List<Merchant>` or an `IEnumerable<Merchant>`, in the same way that a `List<Animal>` isn't a `List<Cat>` even (where `Cat : Animal`), even if the list only contains cats.

Comment: Eric's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817341/3181933) illustrates it particularly well.

Comment: @John - how do I convert it dynamically? Will I have use an interface coz multiple type can come as a part of selector function?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a particularly good way to do that. Showing us a little more of your method help (i.e. can it be made generic?)

Answer (score 2):

@John - Thanks for pointing me to [Eric's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817341/3181933). This makes it clear. 
I fixed it by not calling `AddRange` method, however call `Add` method of the generic collection for each element in the obtained result.

```
splitByRegex(regexPattern, lines, ref lineIndex, capacity, result =>
{
     MethodInfo method = collection.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
     result.Select(selector).ToList().ForEach(item => method.Invoke(collection, new object[] { item }));
});
```