# C# generic cast conversion

Tags: c#, casting

I have a casting problem I am unable to solve :

in ClassA initialize function, I want to pass 'this' as parameter, but the compiler cannot cast from `ClassA<T, U>` to `ClassA<ClassB<U>, U>` knowing that they are the same (`where T : ClassB<U>`).

```
public class ClassA<T, U> : MonoBehaviour where T : ClassB<U>
{
    public void initialize()
    {
        T item =...
        item.Initialize(this); // Cannot implicitly convert from ClassA<T, U> to ClassA<ClassB<U>, U>.
    }
}

public class ClassB<T> : MonoBehaviour
{
    public virtual void Initialize(ClassA<ClassB<T>, T> mgr, T data)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you can cast from `ClassA<T, U>` to `ClassA<ClassB<U>, U>`? Generic classes are invariant. You can't cast a `List<string>` to a `List<object>`, for example. Same thing happens here.

Comment: A and B are not the same.  You can cast from B to A, but not A to B.  Suppose B is a box that can contain a max of 50 marbles.  And A is a box that can contain max 100 marbles.  You can always take B and put into A.   But if you put A into B you are probably going to have a lot of marbles on the floor.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817341/5133585

Comment: well,in the definition of ClassA, you have : "where T : ClassB<U>"

Comment: @Grit that doesn't make any difference whatsoever to what `this` is; that's just a re-statement of `Elephant : Animal` in my answer

Comment: One possible option here might be to make `Initialize` itself generic; not pretty, though

Comment: I just don't get your point. In my understanding, T and ClassB<U> are the same (where T : ClassB<U>)

Comment: @Grit that doesn't mean "the same", though; it means that *any* `T` that is, or inherits from, `ClassB<U>`, is allowed

Comment: ok, I get it.
Is there a way to say "T is ClassB<U>" then?

And thanks everyone for your replies.

Answer (score 10):

Consider: `Elephant : Animal`; this **does not** mean that `List<Elephant> : List<Animal>`, and you cannot cast a `List<Elephant>` to a `List<Animal>` for many reasons (including: that would let you `Add(monkey)` to the `List<Elephant>`, after casting to `List<Animal>`, because `Monkey : Animal`). It is exactly the same here, conceptually.

Comment: this should be added to the MSDN documentation for C# generic types I believe

Answer (score 0):

This does not work for classes. It only works if `ClassB` was an interface with an `out` type parameter as follows:

```
public interface IInterfaceB<out T>
{
   …
}
```

However, an out type parameter means that you can only use the type parameter `T` for return values in your `IInterfaceB` interface members, not for parameters.