# C# generics with inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance

My problem is for some reason, I can't use derived class as the base when I pass it through a generic.

Let's suppose the below code to describe the idea

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual bool IsGood { get; }
}
public class GoodPerson : Person
{
    public override bool IsGood { get; } = true;

}
public class BadPerson : Person
{
    public override bool IsGood { get; } = false;
}

public class Case<T>
{
    public T PersonType { get; set; }
}
public class TypeReflector
{
    public Person Reflect(Case<Person> person)
    {
        if (person.PersonType.IsGood)
            return (GoodPerson)person.PersonType;

        return (BadPerson)person.PersonType;
    }
}
```

and called as below:

```
        var reflector = new TypeReflector();
        var result = reflector.Reflect(new Case<GoodPerson>());
```

why the method `Reflect` can't be called with `Case<GoodPerson>`.
but it possible without the `Case` as below:

```
public Person Reflect(Person person)
{
    if (person.IsGood)
        return (GoodPerson)person;

    return (BadPerson)person;
}
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817341/5133585) might help you understand why `Case<GoodPerson>` is not a kind of `Case<Person>`.

Comment: `Case<Person>` and `Case<GoodPerson>` are different types obviously, you can introduce an interface and use covariance for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Case<Person>` is not the same type as `Case<GoodPerson>` 
Much like.. 
`Case<int>` is not the same type like `Case<string>` 

Your reflector expected a strong type `Case<Person>` but you're providing it a different strong type `Case<GoodPerson>` (so this is like providing `Case<string>` to a method which expects `Case<int>`) 

To make it work, make your reflector accept Case where T is a person or derived class of a person like this:

```
public class TypeReflector
{
    public Person Reflect<T>(Case<T> person) where T:Person
    {
        return person.PersonType;
    }
}
```

But below is what I think you really want to achieve, getting an instance of a type based on properties supplied in descriptor type. A type `Person` once instantiated cannot be "elevated" to `GoodPerson` instance without another `new` keyword somewhere.. (btw, the opposite is possible, creating a `GoodPerson` and casting to the more basic `Person` class)

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp25
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var personDescriptor = new PersonDescriptor { IsGood = true };

            var resultPerson = personDescriptor.CreateInstance();

            Console.WriteLine(resultPerson.IsGood);
            Console.WriteLine(resultPerson.GetType().Name);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class PersonDescriptor
    {
        public bool IsGood { get; set; }

        public Person CreateInstance()
        {
            if (IsGood)
                return new GoodPerson(); //create new instance!
            return new BadPerson(); //create new instance!
        }
    }

    public abstract class Person
    {
        public abstract bool IsGood { get; }
    }

    public class GoodPerson : Person
    {
        public override bool IsGood { get; } = true;
    }

    public class BadPerson : Person
    {
        public override bool IsGood { get; } = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: `if (person.PersonType.IsGood)` doesn't make sense then.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, I agree, I didn't focus on what the method do inside, usually people hide the entire content of their methods implementations, just on the passages between the types. fixed

Comment: `where T: Person` solve the method calling issue, okay.
but what is the benefit of that since I can't use the derived classes `(GoodPerson)person.PersonType`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you already passing GoodPerson, it was instantiated already from your calling code. your reflector just meant to interrogate on the properties - is it not what you wanted?

Comment: @Shrembo I have add another answer - it is not an answer to the question - but I think this is what you really wanted to do. (If I may recommend - you should read  about the Strategy Design Pattern)

Comment: this the part I were locking for "Since Case<Person> is not the same type as Case<GoodPerson>"

Comment: @shrembo understood, but It ok, it is still good info for others who stumble the same area