# Why to use generic with interface constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, constraints

While creating a generic interface, I can define constraint that the generic parameter should inherit from a particular interface(IBase).

```
interface IGeneric<T> where T : IBase
{
    List<T> property{get; set;}
}
```

Is there any use of this? As I can just substitute this with the following interface, which will serve the same purpose and is much simpler.

```
interface IGeneric
{
    List<IBase> property{get; set;}
}
```

It seems to me that we do not need generic at all in this scenario, as we already know that T will be IBase. And the IBase property can already acomodate all its derived types. So what is the use of generic with a specific interface constraint?

Comment: Using generics avoids boxing/unboxing your instances.

Comment: @imsmn That would only apply in the rare case that `IBase` was implemented by a struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two interfaces are very different, because `List<T>` and `List<IBase>` are very different. Let's suppose there is a class `A` that implements `IBase`. This, for one, does not compile:

```
IGeneric noTypeParameter = ...
noTypeParameter.property = new List<A>();
```

But this does:

```
IGeneric<A> hasTypeParameter = ...
noTypeParameter.property = new List<A>();
```

This is because `List` is not covariant on `T`. In fact it is invariant. See also: [Convert List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass)

If you use `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable<IBase>` , then both of the above code snippets will compile, but the two `IGeneric` interfaces are still different, because:

```
IGeneric noTypeParameter = ...
IEnumerable<A> enumerable = noTypeParameter.property; // does not compile


IGeneric<A> hasTypeParameter = ...
IEnumerable<A> enumerable = noTypeParameter.property; //does compile
```

So basically, with the generic parameter, you are able to pass specific types of `List` to the interface, and get specific types of `List` out. However, you can't "store a `property` of any `IBase` implementation". Without a type parameter, you are able to store a `property` of any `IBase` implementation, but you can't get specific types out of/into `IGeneric`.

Comment: Also it does not change anything globally in this case, OP has just `List`, no `IList`.