# How do I test whether a value is a generic list of a parent class?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

Let's say I have a `Child` class that derives from a `Parent` class. How can I write the following function?

```
public bool IsListOfParent(object obj)
{
    // return true if obj implements IList<Parent> (including IList<Child>)
}
```

When I try `return obj is IList<Parent>` it returns false for an object of type `List<Child>`.

Comment: You can't, because `IList<Child>` does not derive from `IList<Parent>` as `IList<T>` is invariant. You can check for `IReadOnlyList<Parent>` though, but that might not be useful for you. (Invariant: since `IList<Parent>` has both getters and setters, you can't assign a value of `IList<Child>` to it, because someone might try to assign a `Parent` value which is not a `Child` but a `Child2` object, so it must be invariant. Whereas `IReadOnlyList<T>` is covariant because it only has getters.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass) in particular [the great Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817341/14868997)

Comment: @Charlieface I don't see why that would be a duplicate... It is quite obvious why cast does not work, but the question (to me) is about categorizing unrelated types rather than casting one type to another. (Should be easy to answer too - check if type is particular generic interface, get type used to construct that type and check if it same/derived from a given type).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, the link is not exactly the answer. I don't want to change the type of anything. I simply want to test whether a value is a generic list of elements that derive from `Parent`.

Comment: And yet you accepted the duplicate... Make sure you decide what exactly you wanted to achieve before asking new/reopening if that duplicate didn't really answer the question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah, that was my mistake. The "duplicate" helped me answer my question, but it wasn't a direct answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov But that has no informational value at all. It doesn't help you to know if `T` is derived from `Parent` because you cannot add a `Parent` object to the list (as it may actually be a `List<Child>` which will not accept it). Checking if it can cast to `IReadOnlyList<Parent>` is actually useful information

Comment: @redcurry What exactly are you trying to do with the information from `IsListOfParent`? In other words: what are you doing that checking a cast to a covariant type such as `IReadOnlyList` does not work?

Comment: @Charlieface I totally agree that the particular information the question asks about is not exactly practical, I only wanted to point out that question looked different.

Comment: @Charlieface I suppose that checking a cast to `IReadOnlyList` could work since I'm not modifying the list. To clarify, the `object` parameter does not need to implement `IReadOnlyList`, correct? In my case, it's possible for the `object` to be an `ObservableCollection`, which doesn't appear to implement `IReadOnlyList`.

Comment: No it doesn't have to, but then it will return false if you do `return obj is IReadOnlyList<T>;` incidentally `ObservableCollection<T>` inherits from `Collection<T>` which does implement `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>` so that would work

Comment: I see why I didn't see `IReadOnlyList<T>`. I'm using .NET Framework 4.0 and `IReadOnlyList<T>` was introduced with .NET Framework 4.5.