# Inheriting super interface from a concrete class?

Tags: c#

I remember in Java once the parent class implements the interface, then all child classes of the parent is now implicitly of type interface (becoming a "super" interface if you will).

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    // Empty
}


// Parent class
public abstract class Mammal : IAnimal
{
    public string Genus { get; set;}
    
    public string Species { get; set; }
}


public class Dog : Mammal // Dog should be of type IAnimal now?
{
    public string FurColor { get; set; }
}


// Some service class that returns a list of Dog objects
public List<Dog> GetMyDogs()
{
    // Build list using Dog class
}


// Consumer
List<IAnimal> animals = GetMyDogs(); // Throws Cannot implicitly convert type Dog to IAnimal
```

Is the same capability available in C#?

Comment: `Dog` does implement `IAnimal`, the problem is that it can't implicitly cast `List<Dog>` to a `List<IAnimal>`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1817300/9363973) Q&A on how to fix this

Comment: A `Dog` is an `IAnimal` but a `List<Dog>` is not a `List<IAnimal>`  because `List<T>` is not **covariant**. See [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033912), which looks to be a duplicate.  Agree?

Comment: The example does not work in Java either.

Comment: @dbc I agree that the variance problem is the underlying cause of the issue, and that the Q&A I linked in my comment is the solution to this issue. In a perfect world we'd close this as a dupe of both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Dog` is an `IAnimal`, but a `List<Dog>` is NOT a `List<IAnimal>`.

If I could do this:

```
List<IAnimal> animals = new List<Dog>();
```

Then I could follow up with this:

```
animals.Add(new Cat());
```

But the list is only a list of dogs. Trying to add a cat would be illegal.

Assigning the list only assigns the reference to the list - it doesn't change the list type.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation about not changing the list type made the most sense to me.