# "SomeClass<X> = SomeClass<T> where T : X" Gives "Cannot implicitly convert SomeClass<T> to SomeClass<X>"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been programming for a while now but am relatively new to c#. Long story short, I need to do the following:

```
public abstract class SomeBaseClass
{

}

public class SomeSmallClass<T> where T : SomeBaseClass
{

}

private List<SomeSmallClass<SomeBaseClass>> listOfData = new List<SomeSmallClass<SomeBaseClass>>();

public void AddToList<T>() where T : SomeBaseClass
{
   listOfData.Add(new SomeSmallClass<T>());
}
```

This gives a nasty red underline and a compiling error that reads "Cannot Implicitly convert SomeSmallClass to SomeSmallClass".

What I don't understand is why the compiler doesn't know that T will always be a SomeBaseClass. Does anyone know what's happening here?

Note: there is no problem with instancing the SomeSmallClass only with adding it to the list.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The error is not `Cannot Implicitly convert SomeSmallClass to SomeSmallClass` it's actually `Cannot convert from SomeSmallClass<T> to SomeSmallClass<SomeBaseClass>` which seems to make sense, [they are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817341/14868997).

Comment: There error does say implicitly but I can't convert at all because doing so (even in a custom converter) would loose data that I am trying to preserve. I need a way that works without this kind of casting.

Comment: See fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/crmXqt is that your code? You don't need to convert, you need to use covariance

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. Yes that is my code. After reading up on covariance I believe I understand the idea. I still don't understand how it could help beyond what is already being done. Could you maybe demonstrate your idea?

Comment: Problem is how does the compiler know that it's safe to assign a `SomeSmallClass<T>` to a variable `SomeSmallClass<SomeBaseClass> x`. What would happen if you did that and then someone tried to do `x.Add(OtherDerivedObject)`? So to prevent that you cannot do this, unless you use covariance. Then the compiler knows that `T` can only appear in an `out` position, and therefore is always safe. This is why you cannot convert `List<Derived>` to `List<Base>`, but you *can* convert `IEnumerable<Derived>` to `IEnumerable<Base>`