# Cast a list of derived types when casting the parent derived class to it's base type

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I have simplified the code for brevity.

There are two base classes, `Document` and `Line` and two classes derived from those, `DocumentPlus` and `LinePlus`.

`Document` and `DocumentPlus` contain a `List<Line>` and `List<LinePlus>` respectively.

```
public class Test
{

    public class Document
    {
        public List<Line> Lines = new List<Line>();
    }

    public class Line
    {
        public string? A;
    }

    public class DocumentPlus : Document
    {
        public new List<LinePlus> Lines = new List<LinePlus>();
    }

    public class LinePlus : Line
    {
        public string? B;
    }
        
    public Test()
    {
        var x = new DocumentPlus();
        x.Lines = new List<LinePlus>()
        {
            new LinePlus() { A = "123", B = "456" },
            new LinePlus() { A = "789", B = "101" },
            new LinePlus() { A = "112", B = "131" }
        };

        var y = (Document)x;

        var z = y.Lines;
        // Z should be the Lines entered above but as their base type
        // Just not sure how to do it!

    }

}
```

Is there any way I can cast the `List<LinePlus>` to `List<Line>` when casting a `DocumentPlus` instance to `Document`?

Thanks!

Comment: Ideally, I don't want to change the class structure (as this mirrors a class that's used heavily throughout the program), but this working is more important.

Comment: Would it be OK to use a (read-only) `IEnumerable` instead of a List in the `Document` base class? IEnumerable is covariant, which means that `List<LinePlus>` is both an `IEnumerable<LinePlus>` as well as a an `IEnumerable<Line>`.

Comment: Your original plan did not work because it violates the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Consider the following example code: `DocumentPlus dp = ...; Document d = dp; d.Lines.Add(new SomeOtherSubtypeOfLine());`. This is usually "fixed" by making Lines read-only in the base class, thus enabling covariance.

Comment: @Heinzi Using `private IEnumerable<Line> _Lines { get; set; } = new List<Line>();` and then implementing two public `List<Line>` and `new List<LinePlus>` in `Document` and `DocumentPlus` respectively, has worked exactly how I wanted it to. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Heinzi if you post that as an answer I'll accept as the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the desired functionality using an answer from this post: [Convert List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass> - Answer by Bigjim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662440/13295405)

This solution uses a wrapper `CastedList<TTo, TFrom>` that implements `IList<TTo>` where interface methods cast items from one generic type to another.

```
public class CastedList<TTo, TFrom> : IList<TTo> where TTo : class where TFrom : class
{
    public IList<TFrom> Items;

    public CastedList(IList<TFrom> items)
    {
        Items = items;
    }

    // IEnumerable
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => Items.GetEnumerator();

    // IEnumerable<T>
    IEnumerator<TTo> IEnumerable<TTo>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new CastedEnumerator<TTo, TFrom>(Items.GetEnumerator());
    }

    // ICollection
    public int Count => Items.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => Items.IsReadOnly;
    public void Add(TTo item)
    {
        if (item is TFrom castItem)
            Items.Add(castItem);
    }
    public void Clear() => Items.Clear();
    public bool Contains(TTo item)
    {
        if (item is TFrom castItem)
            Items.Contains(castItem);
        return false;
    }
    public void CopyTo(TTo[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        if (Items is TFrom[] castArray)
            Items.CopyTo(castArray, arrayIndex);
    }
    public bool Remove(TTo item)
    {
        if (item is TFrom castItem)
            Items.Remove(castItem);
        return false;
    }

    // IList
    public TTo this[int index]
    {
        get => (Items[index] as TTo)!;
        set => Items[index] = (value as TFrom)!;
    }

    public int IndexOf(TTo item)
    {
        if (item is TFrom castItem)
            Items.IndexOf(castItem);
        return -1;
    }
    public void Insert(int index, TTo item)
    {
        if (item is TFrom castItem)
            Items.Insert(index, castItem);
    }
    public void RemoveAt(int index) => Items.RemoveAt(index);
}

public class CastedEnumerator<TTo, TFrom> : IEnumerator<TTo> where TTo : class where TFrom : class
{
    public IEnumerator<TFrom> BaseEnumerator;

    public CastedEnumerator(IEnumerator<TFrom> baseEnumerator)
    {
        BaseEnumerator = baseEnumerator;
    }

    // IDisposable
    public void Dispose() => BaseEnumerator.Dispose();

    // IEnumerator
    object IEnumerator.Current => BaseEnumerator.Current;
    public bool MoveNext() => BaseEnumerator.MoveNext();
    public void Reset() => BaseEnumerator.Reset();

    // IEnumerator<TTo>
    public TTo Current => (BaseEnumerator.Current as TTo)!;

}

public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IList<TTo> CastList<TTo, TFrom>(this IList<TFrom> list) where TTo : class, TFrom where TFrom : class
    {
        return new CastedList<TTo, TFrom>(list);
    }
}

public class Test
{

    public class Document
    {
        public IList<Line> Lines = new List<Line>();
    }

    public class Line
    {
        public string? A;
    }

    public class DocumentPlus : Document
    {
        public new IList<LinePlus> Lines
        {
            get => base.Lines.CastList<LinePlus, Line>();
            set => base.Lines = value.Cast<Line>().ToList();
        }
    }

    public class LinePlus : Line
    {
        public string? B;
    }

    public Test()
    {

        var DocumentP = new DocumentPlus();
        DocumentP.Lines = new List<LinePlus>()
        {
            new LinePlus() { A = "123", B = "456" },
            new LinePlus() { A = "123", B = "456" },
            new LinePlus() { A = "123", B = "456" }
        };

        var x = DocumentP.Lines;
        DocumentP.Lines.Add(new LinePlus());

        var Document = (Document)DocumentP;

        Document.Lines.Add(new LinePlus() { A = "789", B = "789" });
        Document.Lines.Add(new Line() { A = "456" });
        Document.Lines.Add(new Line() { A = "262" });

    }

}
```

Comment: This resolves the issue where a new list is created every time the `Lines` property in `DocumentPlus` is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can cast the list of LinePlus to Line when casting a DocumentPlus instance to Document?

No, because the `List<LinePlus>` belongs to `DocumentPlus` and not `Document`.

`DocumentPlus` uses the `new` keyword when declaring `Lines`. This indicates that you want to use method hiding rather than overriding; `Document.Lines` is still of type `List<Line>` and does not reference the same instance as `DocumentPlus.Lines`.

In fact they can't reference the same instance because `List<LinePlus>` is unrelated to `List<Line>`, considering `List<T>` is generically invariant.

---

If you simply want to *convert* `DocumentPlus.Lines` to a `List<Line>`, then that's perfectly possible:

```
var z = x.Lines.ConvertAll(linePlus => (Line)linePlus);
```

But it seems that your intended inheritance hierarchy is broken.

Comment: Yeah, I put the new keyword there as a temporary measure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
using System.Linq

public Document CastDocPlusToDoc(DocumentPlus inputDocP) {
    Document outputDoc = new Document();
    outputDoc.Lines.AddRange(inputDocP.LinesPlus.Cast<Lines>());
}

var y = CastDocPlusToDoc(x)
```

I'm not even sure that .Cast is necessary here

Comment: I've used a combination of two answers, put a method that returns Document in the DocumentPlus class and had it assign `base.Lines = Lines.ConvertAll<Line>(p =>p);` and then `return this;`

Comment: I had used that until Heinzi suggested using IEnumerable which has given more desirable syntax. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

The (possible) "correct" way to approach this is with generics - then no casting is required. You just get the right type of `Line` when enumerating the collection.

```
public class Document<TLine> where TLine : Line
{
    public List<TLine> Lines = new List<TLine>();
}

public class Line
{
    public string? A;
}

public class DocumentPlus : Document<LinePlus>
{
}

public class LinePlus : Line
{
    public string? B;
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BbfOAN

---

As commented, this might more closely suit your requirements

```
public class DocumentBase<TLine> where TLine : Line
{
    public List<TLine> Lines = new List<TLine>();
}

public class Line
{
    public string? A;
}

public class Document : DocumentBase<Line>
{
}

public class DocumentPlus : DocumentBase<LinePlus>
{
}

public class LinePlus : Line
{
    public string? B;
}
```

This approach gives you type safety, and thus does not require you to cast to `LinePlus` when dealing with `DocumentPlus` instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to avoid generics as I want `Line` to be used in `Document` and `LinePlus` to be used in `DocumentPlus`. This would allow access to extra fields included in `LinePlus` that aren't required.

Comment: @Avallex Make `Document<TLine>` called `DocumentBase<TLine>` and then just define `Document : DocumentBase<Line>` and `DocumentPlus : DocumentBase<LineBase>` and now you have type safety, and your requirement to use `Line` in `Document`

Comment: Just having a play now, I can't cast a `DocumentPlus` instance to `Document` as `DocumentPlus` is no longer derived from `Document`. The problem I needed to solve was accessing `Lines` as a `List<Line>` as member of `Document` and as `List<LinePlus>` as a member of `DocumentPlus`

Comment: @Avallex I think you have a classic XYProblem. Either `DocumentPlus` _isa_ `Document`, in which case there is an inheritance hierarchy and it inherits the properties of `Document` (including their type). Or it's not, and in which case it doesn't!

Comment: Also, regarding _"The problem I needed to solve was accessing Lines as a List<Line> as member of Document and as List<LinePlus> as a member of DocumentPlus"_ - that is **exactly** the problem that the generic solution solves

Comment: Yes, there is an inheritance hierarchy and `DocumentPlus` inherits many properties from `Document` in the actual code. Apologies if this XY like. I'm not understanding how the generic will help in this situation as I'm looking to retain this casting behaviour: `Document y = (Document)x;` (where x is `DocumentPlus`) - I can expand the question so that it includes a few class members from the actual code. I've posted an answer containing the solution that worked for me based on Heinzi's answer.

Comment: To avoid the XY, we need to not know _how you're trying to solve a problem_ but *why*.  Why do you need to treat `x` as a `Document` but still need its `Lines` as the type implied by `x` - ie `LinePlus`. Essentially, it is not clear what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: But if you have an acceptable solution, I suggest you just move on ;)

Comment: It would appear I do not.