# How to cast ImmutableArray<DerivedClass> to ImmutablyArray<BaseClass> and vice versa in C#?

Tags: c#, casting, immutable-collections

I know it's not possible to cast derived lists (why not is nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817341/3457154)), but what about ImmutableArrays as they cannot be changed casting should be valid, right?

I would expect this to work:

```
class Animal {}
class Dog : Animal {}

ImmutableArray<Dog> dogs = ImmutableArray.Create<Dog>(new Dog());
ImmutableArray<Animal> animals = (ImmutableArray<Animal>) dogs;
ImmutableArray<Dog> dogsBack = (ImmutableArray<Dog>) animals;
```

Comment: Why would you want to? Can't you access `dogs` as if it contained `Animal` instances or add `Dog` instances to `animals` on creation?

Comment: @ChrisBD I need this for a caching scenario, I made an example [here](https://gist.github.com/DomenPigeon/27e28a1a77e12aa5ad0d4d31a7932762)

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible:

```
ImmutableArray<Dog> dogs = ImmutableArray.Create<Dog>(new Dog());
ImmutableArray<Animal> animals = ImmutableArray<Animal>.CastUp(dogs);
ImmutableArray<Dog> dogsBack = animals.CastArray<Dog>();
```

Note that you could also use [`CastArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1.castarray) to cast from dogs to animals, but due to covariance, [`CastUp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1.castup) is a significantly faster than the `CastArray` method.

Comment: Why do you need `ImmutableArray`'s `CastUp`? `dogs.CastArray<Animal>()` should be enough?

Comment: @PeterCsala both operations simply cast the underlying array with zero copy; "enough" suggests a difference - if anything, `CastUp` is preferable since it exploits a *known* covariance operation, rather than an unknown blind cast with type-test; source, for the curious: https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/dotnet-collections/blob/master/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableArray%601.cs#L1048-L1064