# In C#, why does the 'is' operator behave like this in the following situations?

Tags: c#, operators

I have the following code in a .Net6 console application.

```
internal class Program

    {

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            var x = new SomethingUser<Something>();

            var y = new SomethingUser<ISomething>();

 

            Console.WriteLine(x is ISomethingUser<Something>);

            Console.WriteLine(y is ISomethingUser<ISomething>);

            Console.WriteLine(x is SomethingUser<ISomething>);

            Console.WriteLine(y is SomethingUser<ISomething>);

 

            Console.Read();

        }

    }


    public class Something : ISomething {}

    public class SomethingUser<T> : ISomethingUser {}

    public interface ISomething {}
 
    public interface ISomethingUser<T> {}
}
```

The actual output is:
True,
True,
False,
True

Can someone explain why the is check evaluates to false for the third scenario please?

I expected the output to be:
True,
True,
True,
True

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate question but I can't immediately find a dupe.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass

Answer (score 0):

Because `SomethingUser<Something>` and `SomethingUser<ISomething>` are different types. C# has covariance for generic parameters of interfaces and delegates only, but not for classes.

From [ECMA-334 C# standard 6th edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_6th_edition_june_2022.pdf), ch. 17.2.3.1:

> Variant type parameter lists can only occur on interface and delegate types.

...

> If the variance annotation is `out`, the type parameter is said to be covariant.

Btw, you may slightly improve compatibility by declaring `ISomethingUser` to be covariant by adding `out` specification for generic parameter `public interface ISomethingUser<out T> {}`, then `x is ISomethingUser<ISomething>` will return `true`. So by casting to interface, still no covariance for classes.

Comment: "then x is ISomethingUser<ISomething> will return true" returns true when ISomethingUser is declared as "ISomethingUser<T>" as well. It doesn't relate to "x is SomethingUser<ISomething>" which is asked about.

Comment: @rotabor The point is you *can* use covariance on  an interface, but not on a class, so if `SomethingUser` was instead an interface then it might work, assuming only out-positioned values.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently `x` doesn't meet any condition enlisted below against `SomethingUser<ISomething>`:

([Type-testing operators and cast expressions - is, as, typeof and casts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast))

The is operator returns true when an expression result is non-null and any of the following conditions are true:

- The run-time type of an expression result is T.
- **The run-time type of an expression result derives from type T, implements interface T, or another implicit reference conversion exists from it to T**.
- The run-time type of an expression result is a nullable value type with the underlying type T and the Nullable.HasValue is true.
- A boxing or unboxing conversion exists from the run-time type of an expression result to type T.

The code below demonstrates the most close case:

```
var x = new SomethingUser<Something>();
SomethingUser<ISomething> z; // x is SomethingUser<ISomething> ?
z = x;
-->
 error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'SomethingUser<Something>' to 'SomethingUser<ISomething>'
```

To allow conversions such as `T<A>` <--> `T<B>`, where `A` inherits `B`, variance of `T<A>` to `A` should be explicitly defined using `in` or `out` variance modifiers. But it's allowed only when `T` is an interface or a delegate not a class.

The conversions between `A<T>` and `B<T>` are allowed according to inheritance relationship between `A` and `B` (cases 1 and 2).

The general approach is well explained in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to explain this by way of an example showing what would happen if such a conversion was possible.

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
public interface IMammal
{
}

public sealed class Dog: IMammal
{
    public void Woof() { Console.WriteLine("Woof"); }
}

public sealed class Cat: IMammal
{
    public void Meow() { Console.WriteLine("Meow");}
}
```

Now consider the following code:

```
// You can add Dogs AND Cats to a List<IMammal>:

var mammals = new List<IMammal>();

mammals.Add(new Dog()); // OK, a Dog is a Mammal.
mammals.Add(new Cat()); // OK, a Cat is a Mammal.

// Here's a list of Cats.

var cats = new List<Cat>();

List<IMammal> reallyListOfCats = cats; // Doesn't compile!

reallyListOfCats.Add(new Dog()); // And this is why! Chaos would ensue.

cats[0].Meow(); // What happens now? This is a Dog, and Dog's go "woof"!
```

The first part of that just demonstrates that you can put `Dog`s AND `Cat`s into a `List<IMammal>`.

The next part shows what could happen if you allow a `List<Cat>` to be assigned to a `List<IMammal>`: If the line marked *Doesn't compile!* actually DID compile, it would mean that `reallyListOfCats` would allow you to add a `Dog` to it, although it's really a list of `Cat`s.

So now `cats[0]` is actually a `Dog` so when you call `cats[0].Meow()` it would explode.

Note that `reallyListOfCats` would be an alias for `cats` if this code compiled, so if you modify `reallyListOfCats` you are also modifying `cats` because they both reference the selfsame object.

Answer (score 0):

Just a counter-example to explain why `SomethingUser<Something>` cannot be `SomethingUser<ISomething>`.

Assume the `SomethingUser<T>` class has a property with a setter:

```
public class SomethingUser<T> : ISomethingUser<T>
{
    public T Thing { set; }
}
```

And a new class `Foo` implementes the `ISomething` interface:

```
public class Foo : ISomething {}
```

Now if it is able to convert `SomethingUser<Something>` to `SomethingUser<ISomething>`, you will get:

```
var x = new SomethingUser<Something>();
if(x is SomethingUser<ISomething> xx)
    xx.Thing = new Foo(); // What?
```

You can see that at the beginning, the type of the `Thing` property of `x` was `Something`, but this false conversion allows us to set any object that implements the `ISomething` interface to it, which obviously should not happen.