Cannot implicitly convert list of derived objects to generic IEnumerable<T> where T is a base type
I have a type system like
class Base {}
class Derived1 : Base {}
class Derived2 : Base {}

I have also collections of derived types
class MyClass
{
    List<Derived1> Derived1Collection { get; set; }
    List<Derived2> Derived2Collection { get; set; }
}

I want to have a generic method that returns any from these collections like GetData<Derived1>(). Have implemented it like so:
class MyClass
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>() where T : Base
        => typeof(T) switch // dummy "typeof(T)"
        {
            _ when typeof(T) == typeof(Derived1) => Derived1Collection,
            _ when typeof(T) == typeof(Derived2) => Derived2Collection,
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"{typeof(T)} isn't supported."),
        };
}

For every returning of derived collection it writes an error like "Cannot implicitly convert type List<Derived1> to IEnumerable<T>". But after adding casting at each derived collection it is gone, so this works:
_ when typeof(T) == typeof(Derived1) => Derived1Collection.Cast<T>(),
_ when typeof(T) == typeof(Derived2) => Derived2Collection.Cast<T>(),

Why so?

Only because Derived inherits Base doesn't mean List<Derived> also inherits or is convertible to a List<Base>. See this question for why this is so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass, in particular Eric Lipperts answer.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain while that's true, I don't believe this is the problem and also not the question here.

Because you're using reflection to check the type at runtime, and return the correct collection accordingly. Whilst logically the correct collection type will be returned, this isn't statically checked by the compiler.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain OP tries to convert to IEnumerable<T> though which is the case due to covariance.


Why so?

Basically because compiler does not (at least at the moment) deduce the type based on the typeof(T) ==  check for further type checks. It can work "the other way around" with type-testing (since the IEnumerable<T> is covariant):
class MyClass1
{
    private List<Derived1> Derived1Collection { get; set; } = new() { new Derived1() };
    List<Derived2> Derived2Collection { get; set; } = new() { new Derived2() };

    public IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>() where T : Base
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Base))
            throw new Exception(); // otherwise the first if will match
        
        if (Derived1Collection is IEnumerable<T> d1)
            return d1;
        if (Derived2Collection is IEnumerable<T> d2)
            return d2;
        
        throw new Exception();
    }
}

Note that direct collection cast will work for you case too:
public IEnumerable<T> GetData1<T>() where T : Base
    => typeof(T) switch // dummy "typeof(T)"
    {
        _ when typeof(T) == typeof(Derived1) => (IEnumerable<T>)Derived1Collection,
        _ when typeof(T) == typeof(Derived2) => (IEnumerable<T>)Derived2Collection,
        _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"{typeof(T)} isn't supported."),
    };


"Note that direct collection cast will work for you case too:" - hmmm, it sounds better, than using Enumerable casting, because it doesn't require to traverse the whole collection at every call for GetData method. Or not?

@Alex34758 basically yes though in most cases the performance difference should not very noticeable in majority of apps/cases.
