How do you cast an generic class into an generic class of object?
let's say that you have 2 classes:
public abstract class Foo<T> {
    public abstract T DoSomething();
}

public class FooInt : Foo<int> {
    public override int DoSomething() {
        return 42;
    }
}

I want to cast FooInt into Foo<object>.
And it is hard to restructure the code because I have a List<Foo<object>> that stores all the Foo class instances.
And I do want to keep the overrides of FooInt.

I have tried this:
public static implicit operator Foo<object>(Foo<T> field) { return (Foo<object>)field; }

But I got an Overflow Exception, because it called itself. Then I tried this:
public static implicit operator Foo<object>(Foo<T> field) { return (field as Foo<object>)!; }

But that returned null. And I tried this:
public static implicit operator Foo<object>(Foo<T> field) { return (Foo<object>)(object)field;}

But that gave an Invalid Cast Exception. And I also tried removing the cast but that didn't work either.

You cannot. Foo<object> and Foo<TthatIsNotObject> are two completely unrelated types.

But how do I store different types of Foo in a List? @Fildor

Either use a non-generic Foo or a common interface. - Maybe a non-generic Foo base class from which Foo<T> inherits. That could act as common interface. => https://dotnetfiddle.net/HbBF2T

"But how do I store different types of Foo in a List?" - If that's the actual problem you want to solve, you should actually ask that instead. Casting Foo<int> to Foo<object> in this example makes no sense because there isn't any definition for Foo<object> shown in the first place, and no reason to suppose that it and its doSomething implementation - assuming both even exist - is compatible with the Foo<int> logic.

Anyway, please check out the [tour] and keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum - your thanks are assumed, not necessary, and generally considered a distraction that will be edited out.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass

^^ Also note Eric Lippert's answer on that one.

@Fildor comments , like this
public interface IFoo
{
    void DoSome();
}

public abstract class Foo<T> : IFoo
{
    public abstract T DoSomething();
    public void DoSome()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}

public class FooInt : Foo<int>
{
    public override int DoSomething()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
public class FooDouble : Foo<double>
{
    public override double DoSomething()
    {
        return 42.0;
    }
}


List<IFoo> list = new List<IFoo>()
   {
       new FooInt(),
       new FooDouble()
   };
 foreach (var item in list)
 {
     item.DoSome();
 }


But can I still call DoSomething from IFoo, or else, how do I cast it back? @TimChang

I edit my answer , but it still can not get return value. @0xDED

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oW5R3J

@0xDED ok , you done.

You could declare a covariant interface:
public interface IFoo<out T>
{
    T DoSomething();
}
public class Foo<T> : IFoo<T>
{
    public T DoSomething() => default;
}

that would allow you to write IFoo<object> a = new Foo<MyClass>();. But would still not allow IFoo<object> b = new Foo<int>(). For that I think you would need an adapter:
public class FooObjectAdapter<T>(IFoo<T> foo) : IFoo<object>
{
    public object DoSomething() => (object)foo.DoSomething();
}
IFoo<object> b = new FooObjectAdapter<int>(new Foo<int>());

