Getting the C# compiler to infer IList<IInterface<T>> when passed List<U> where U implements IInterface<T>
I have a function that looks like this:
    public void Proc<T>(string paramName, IList<IInterface<T>> paramValue)
        where T : AncestorType, new()
    {
    }

When I call it with a List<U> where U is a class that implements IInterface<T> where T derives from AncestorType, the overload resolution doesn't work.
I can do this, of course:
    public void Proc<R, T>(string paramName, IList<R> paramValue)
        where R : IInterface<T>
        where T : AncestorType, new()
    {
    }

But then I have to explicitly specify the type parameters when calling the function.
Or I can have the LINQ that does the ToList() explicitly make an IInterface<T> rather than an R but that's also a bit cumbersome.
Am I missing an elegant solution where the compiler can still infer this and I avoid explicit casts?

overload-resolution "doesn't work" simply because a List<Dervied> is no IList<Base>. See this question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass
